# JMeter -XPath2 Extractor not working as XPath

Tags: xpath, jmeter, extractor

I tried to use JMeter [recommendation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) to move to XPath2 over XPath Extractor

> Since JMeter 5.0, you should use XPath2 Extractor as it provides better and easier namespace management, better performances and support for XPath 2.0

But for simple query I get no results, for output

```
<Object classId="QueryResultRow"><Property i:type="fn40:SingletonId" propertyId="Id"><Value>{abc-def}</Value></Property><Property i:type="fn40:SingletonString" propertyId="DCN"><Value>D112345</Value></Property></Object>
```

I use query `/Object/Property/Value` or `//Object//Property//Value` and it works only in XPath and not XPath2

Results:

```
Value={abc-def}
Value_1={abc-def}
Value_2=D112345
Value_matchNr=2
```

Same results with `/*[local-name()='Object']/*[local-name()='Property']/*[local-name()='Value']` as @EdBangga suggested

Is there an issue with XPath2 Extractor or major change of syntax?

Comment: have you tried /*[local-name()='Object']/*[local-name()='Property']/*[local-name()='Value']?

Comment: @EdBangga same result with `/*[local-name()='Object']/*[local-name()='Property']/*[local-name()='Value']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to namespaces in your XML (i)

Once you show the full XML with namespaces I can give more information but to summarize:

- you'll need to configure alias i to match the full namespace (you can use XPath2 Tester and Show Namespaces aliases)
- then it should work

Comment: It's part of XML,so it can't be parse in XPath2?

Comment: I don't understand. I guess what you show is an excerpt right ? Can you show the full xml which will contains the namespace declaration and help solving issue